# Obtener ítem anterior en una ObservableCollection desordenada

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una `ObservableCollection` con ítems de la siguiente clase:

```
public partial class consultaSelect
{

    private string scriptField;

    private string nombreAccionField;

    private string iconoField;

    private string ordenField;

    private string tooltipField;

    private string valueField;

   //Todos con sus getters y setter respectivos.
}
```

La propiedad que me interesa acá es `orden`. La misma se usa para ordenar esta *collection*. El problema es que `orden` puede tener agujeros, es decir, puede existir algo así `1,2,5,7,9` guardado como se le ocurra al deserializador (es una clase que se carga desde un *XML*).

El tema es que por la vista, el usuario puede cambiar el `orden` de dos ítems, y para eso lo que hace es moverlo en la vista (todo eso anda y está solucionado). El problema viene, porque si el usuario quiere mover una posición para *"arriba"*, el ítem `5`, este debería pasar a ser `2`, y el `2` pasaría a ser `5`.

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo hago de una forma elegante para obtener cuál es el máximo ítem que es menor a una cantidad determinada?

Se puede hacer con un `while` a la antigua, lo que busco es una solución *Linq* moderna que devuelva eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución en Linq puede ser la siguiente, bajo el supuesto que tienes el elemento pivote y la propiedad a buscar es `ordenField:

1. Ordenar la lista
2. Encontrar el índice del elemento a buscar
3. Con base en el punto 2, encontrar el índice anterior
4. Obtener la información del índice anterior

Teniendo como entrada los datos: `1`, `2`, `5`, `7`, `9`:

```
string EstoyParadoEn = "5";
elemento = lista.OrderBy(t => t.ordenField)
    .ElementAt(lista.IndexOf(lista.Where(t => t.ordenField == EstoyParadoEn)
    .FirstOrDefault()) - 1).ordenField;
```

La salida sería: `2`.

Otra forma de resolverlo es con:

```
elemento = lista.Where(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.ordenField) < Convert.ToInt32(EstoyParadoEn))
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.ordenField).FirstOrDefault().ordenField;
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración y el resultado](http://rextester.com/UMQ10508)</kbd>